# How to produce and import multiple key frame object animations into Verold

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, verold

Not sure if this is a Verold or a 3ds Max problem. I have a scene to import into Verold, with objects that  animate. I want the objects to complete one animation when clicked, and then start another animation (on loop) when clicked again. What is the pipeline for getting the animations in? I can see how to do it with the character animation file on the Verold tutorial, because you can import just a skelton .fbx, but for objects, you have to import the whole scene each time, no? I am not worried about how to deal with the event handler side, it is getting the animations in. Do I produce the two animations in 3ds Max one after the other in the timeline and then call on them separately somehow? Or do I produce two scenes with identical objects but with different animations and then somehow extract the animation alone? In other words, what does Verold need and how do I get there?

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches will work.

First, if you have a single file in 3ds Max, with both animations in a single timeline, you will need to split the timeline into two takes (clips) inside Verold. You can do this as follows:

1. Click on the animation asset
2. In the Inspector, select the first take
3. Click Duplicate to duplicate the take
4. Adjust the start and stop times of each take

Then you can trigger the two takes independently with the Event Handler.

Alternatively, you can create two separate files, each with a different animation. When you import the files into Verold, you will end up with two animation assets. You can trigger these two animations independently with the Event Handler.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. One more question... in the event handler, is it possible to trigger animations sequentially through the same action, i.e. click an object to start one animation, then click the same object again to start the second?

Comment: I don't mean to have the first as a default animation already running when you open the scene, I mean have a static scene first, then click once for first anim, then again for second?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, that's not yet possible. The event handler is for basic interactivity, and we're working on a next release with support for more advanced features.

What I might suggest for now is to use custom actions on your scene, one for each of your animations. This still wouldn't let you do sequential animations, but at least that lets you trigger both of your animations.

If you send an email to info@verold.com, I'll add you to our list, and get you in as a beta user on our timeline tool. Should be in the next few weeks.

Ross

Comment: Can you clarify "custom actions" please?